# Rendering an Array with React Async is Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am retrieving data from a REST service. The data comes back as an array. This is the function I use to retrieve the data.

```
export function fetchMessage() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/currencies`, {
      headers: { token: localStorage.getItem('token') }
    })
     .then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
       dispatch({
         type: FETCH_MESSAGE,
         payload: response.data
       });
     });
  }
}
```

The output from `fetchMessage` is an array of Objects.

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
    addedDate:"2013-08-22"
    ccyCode:"CHF"
    country:"SCHWIZER FRANC"
    lastChangeDate:"2016-05-02"
    offerRate:7.02
    prevRate:8.501
    prevRateDate:"2016-04-01"
    rate:8.425
    rateDate:"2016-05-01"
    unit:1
    __proto__:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
```

The `fetchMessage` function is called by the component below.

```
class Feature extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchMessage();
    //console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.message}</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { message: state.auth.message };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Feature);
```

The component can't render the message because it is an

```
bundle.js:1256 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ccyCode, country, unit, rateDate, rate, prevRateDate, prevRate, offerRate, addedDate, lastChangeDate}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Feature`.(…)
```

I've tried to run a map of the `this.props.message` like this

```
<div>
        {this.props.message.map(
          function(object){
            return ('Something'
            );
          }
        )}
</div>
```

But I get an error message saying that I can't run `map` on `message`. How can I render the data in the object? Do I need to save it in some other way? How do I iterate over the objects to render them?

Comment: Try something like this: `<div>{this.props.message.ccyCode} {this.props.message.rate}</div>` and go from there.

Comment: @ChrisG I tried both `<div>{this.props.message.ccyCod}</div>` and `<div>{this.props.message.rate}</div>` and both gives the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rate' of undefined` the undefined property of course change to `ccyCode` when I try with `ccyCode`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: I think your issue is just that `this.props.message` is undefined on the initial render. Try rendering `null` if it's not set.

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.message) return null
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.message.map(message => {
        return (
          <div key={message.ccyCode}>...
            {message.ccyCode} {message.rate} ...
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

My answer below might still be helpful if anyone is interested in dynamically rendering an Object.

I'm assuming you want to dynamically render the data from the objects, as opposed to having to explicitly render each field.

Try iterating through [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and render the data.

```
<div>
    {Object.keys(this.props.message).map(key => {
        return (
          <div key={key}> // you need a dynamic, unique key here to not get a React warning
            {key}: {this.props.message[key]}
          </div>
        )
      }
    )}
</div>
```

If you want to just show the data for debugging/inspection purposes, I've found this is very helpful.

```
<pre>
  {JSON.stringify(this.props.message,null,2)}
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Brad. The JSON Stringify renders the whole object. But when I try the `Object.keys` setting `<div key={ccyCode}>` then I get `ReferenceError: ccyCode` is not defined. I don't understand what you mean by "undefined on the initial render"? Is there a second render? Using the if statement I guess will just result in nothing/null being rendered?

Comment: First off, where is `ccyCode` defined? Typically you use a value from the mapped record. So you might just need to reference it like `this.props.message[key].ccyCode`. Second, Because you're calling the API async in `componentWillMount()`, it will render initially without the data, and then a 2nd time when the response updates state.

Comment: Also, my response was assuming you wanted to render an Object, per your question. If you're wanting to render all of the array results, I think the error should clear up when you fix that initial render error.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I changed to
 ` <div key={this.props.message[key].ccyCode}>
              {key}: {this.props.message[key].ccyCode}
            </div>`
 which give the output 
`0: CHF
1: DKK
2: EUR...` 
Just what I want. Just a one questions I set my key with `key={this.props.message[key].ccyCode}` but then when I use ` {key}` then the output is a number. What is it that I'm missing in my understanding?

Comment: Its hard to say.. are you wanting to dynamically iterate through all fields of an object, or all the objects in the array? Are you using `Object.keys` are still just the map?

Comment: My guess is that `this.props.message` is an Array, not an Object. As such, `Object.keys(someArray)` just returns the indexes. You probably just want to do something like `this.props.message.map(item => {...})`. `Object.keys` was only if you wanted to iterate through an Object (per your question title).

Comment: Thanks Brad. I'm still very new to React and JS so I'm still a bit confused sometimes. I'm using using below now. 
`<div>
        {Object.keys(this.props.message).map(key => {
          return (
            <div key={this.props.message[key].ccyCode}>
              {key}: {this.props.message[key].ccyCode} {this.props.message[key].rate}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>`

Comment: I updated my answer... try the new code (without Object.keys).